# After enabling client-to-node encryption, opscenter can't connect to cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

What is needed for OpsCenter to talk to datastax enterprise cassandra nodes via SSL? This is Datastax enterprise 4.5.3 and OpsCenter 5.0.1.

I have created certs, keystore and truststore for all nodes, and enabled node-to-node ssl encryption. Seems to be working fine. nodetool shows all nodes up and running normally.

I have also enabled ssl between opscenter and datastax-agent on each node. Also seems to be working. I can see all the nodes in the Opscenter web UI - "all agents connected"

But as soon as I enable client-to-node encryption in cassandra.yaml, opscenter says it's unable to connect to the cluster. So what are my missing steps?

The object is to create a secure multi-region cluster in AWS using elastic ip addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Have you edited your cluster in OpsCenter to set it up for client-to-node encryption? In OpsCenter, click Settings > Cluster Connections. If you have multiple clusters, select yours from the dropdown. Check "Client to node encryption is enabled on my cluster" and enter the cert settings that follow. That should do it.

Comment: the dropdown says "CA Certificate file path". What is needed here? I read somewhere it had to be a pem file? I suppose it will have to be added to the truststore?

Comment: Yes, it must be PEM encoded. You can easily convert it to PEM from CER using the instructions here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/online_help/opscAddingCluster_t.html